How to listen to user sentence and recognize same sentence to perform a task? - Android native or React Native
How to approach the development of this below app?
So I want to build a simple Counter app, but the catch is, instead of user manually tapping a button each time to increase the count. I want to add a recording option, once the user records a word or a sentence, every time the app hears this sentence/word it should automatically increase a count.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What I assume from your question is you want a Speech-to-text library, React Native Voice library, you pass the locale into the function, then get the result and check what the user asked for using regex to filter the result, and get the number out of it and perform your task. For more please please clarify your message further.
